# Why Can't I Set My Flash Intensity with My Phottix Odin 2 in Manual Mode

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, phottix

I have two speedlites. A Phottix Mitros and a Sunpak PZ42X. I can control flash intensity in both of them in TTL mode. I can also control the zoom (for Mitros it works, a bit buggy with Sunpak; whenever I try to set zoom in Sunpak it resets to what is previously set in the speedlite).

However, when I switch to manual mode, I cannot control the flash intensity for the Mitros. It might not be compatible with Sunpak but it's supposed to just work with the Mitros.

What could I be doing wrong?

PS: I do not know much about flash.

**EDIT:**

I am controlling the speedlites wirelessly via a set of Odin 2 transmitter and receivers. I am using the Odin 2 transmitter to adjust the flash intensity and zoom and to switch between TTL and Manual.

Comment: There are a lot of needed details left out of the question. Are you using the flashes on the hot shoe? Or via a set of wireless triggers? How are you trying to control the flash? Via the camera's (what type of camera) menu? Via a wireless transmitter's menu?

Comment: Do you have the Mitros? Or the Mitros+?

Comment: Also, are you judging the power level of the flash from images you've taken, or from the reading on the flashs' LCDs?

Comment: I am using the Mitros (no +). I based the power level on both the flash LCD and the images taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I asked a Phottix rep same question and here is his answer:

You have to set the flash on TTL, mounted on an Odin 2 receiver, and from there you can set the flash intensity on both TTL and Manual on the Odin 2 transmitter.

I tested it out and it indeed is working (based on the images taken, not on the flash LCD)

Comment: Yes. This seems to be a quirk of the Odin system: flashes have to be in TTL mode for power control to work, and it only displays correctly on the TX unit.

Answer (score 0):

The flash has to be set on Ettl to mode. That drove me crazy until I figured it out. They need to publish that in manual.